# Isolate Proton game from internet without breaking Steam API

Tags: networking, iptables, steam

Scenario:

There are two widely suggested ways to force Steam games to run offline. These two ways are to either use `unshare` in the game's command line options:

```
unshare -r -n %command%
```

Or to use `iptables` to deny network access to a user group and then launching the game as that user group:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP

sudo -E -g no-internet %command%
```

---

The problem:

On my Arch laptop, trying with Dark Souls PTDE (modded, so I need to play offline), both alternatives produce the same result: The game terminates after a few seconds. In both cases, the Proton log reveals a problem with the Steam API:

```
19409.208:0020:0024:err:steam:setup_steam_registry SteamAPI_Init failed
```

This issue seems related, but it's been closed without solution:
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-runtime/issues/285

A friend tells me that it's because Steam API uses socket which is in the namespace, but I don't know much about this topic.

---

My question:

Is there some way to block the game from connecting to the servers without breaking Steam API? I know it's possible to just manually turn off your network on each launch, but that is really inconvenient, and I'd like to be able to use other network apps (e.g. for streaming or voice chat) even while the game remains offline.

To put the issue more generally: It would probably be useful to have a method to isolate apps from the internet that is more selective than `unshare -r -n` or `iptables -A OUTPUT ... -j DROP`. Does such a method exist?

Answer (score 2):

After some time of testing, I was able to make it work.

I used the iptables way, you have to create a no-internet group, add the user to that group, in iptables add rule:
`iptables -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP`

`! -o lo` means ignore localhost interface.

The game should be run with this parameters:
`sg no-internet -c "%command%"`

I did a little workaround:

Create file `/home/username/.local/bin/no-internet`:

```python
#!/bin/python
import subprocess
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    command = ""
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        command += " " + arg.replace(" ", "\\ ")
    subprocess.run(f"sg no-internet -c '{command.strip()}'", shell=True)
```

Save and add `chmod +x`

Now the game can be run `no-internet %command%`, main thing is that `~/.local/bin` should be in the PATH.